# A tableview within a stack view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, stack

I would like to implement a tableview within a stack view in Xcode (Swift). 
I have no problem putting it all together in the Storyboard. I am using an UIViewController to control the various stack views but I just can't figure out how to hook-up the tableview.

Possibly its best to abandon the stack view concept. Prefer not to because it does a neat job of certain display issues.

Answer (score 0):

For hooking it up, it makes no difference whether your table view is in a stack view or not.  You need to set the table view's delegate and data source, probably to your view controller(that's the quick and dirty place to hook it up).  You should be able to do that in interface builder(make sure your VC conforms to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource)  Now table views have no intrinsic size, so if it runs but you can't see it, you might have to give it a size to get it to appear correctly(subclass UITableView and give it an intrinsic content size, or, probably simpler, add constraints on its height/width)

Comment: Thanks, will give that a try.  
The table appears perfectly on run - so size is fine.

Comment: get this error /Users/jeremyandrews/Documents/swift/ARUA Swift 3/ARUA/ControlRoom/ControlRoom/ControlRoomViewController.swift:11:7: Type 'ControlRoomViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'
when I add DataSource. in may class:
 ControlRoomViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

Comment: UITableViewDataSource has 2 required methods numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath that you'll have to implement.   Look for a tutorial on table views for some example code.  You should be able to follow them almost exactly.

Comment: my problem is not with tableviews themselves - I have implemented quite a few - its implementing one that is contained in a stackview that is creating a problem for me.

Comment: In particular is the datasource issue that keeps throwing an NSException.

Comment: what's the exception and where is it being thrown?  Does your VC's numberOfRowsInSection get called before the exception?

Comment: Oops ! A real newbie mistake - a typo error on the reuse identifier - apologies and thanks